# Cannot find module 'angular2/core' in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: typescript, angular

I came across this error **Cannot find module 'angular2/core'** when trying out the **angular2 beta** version in **Visual Studio 2015 Update 1**.

The code is below:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core"

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I have the *angular2 beta* version in my *Visual Studio ASP.NET 5* project. I have also enabled compile TS files when building the project.

A few things that I tried, but none worked:

1. I added `/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts" />` at the top of the **ts** file.

2.

```
import {Component} from "angular2/bundles/angular2"

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

3.

```
import {Component} from "../node_modules/angular2/core"

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: "<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>"
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

UPDATE:

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

UPDATE:

I added **"moduleResolution": "node"** to **tsconfig.json** file, but now I get another set of errors:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Terminal.Web, Configuration:
>   Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(6,14):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(9,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(10,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(248,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(283,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(290,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(346,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(498,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(561,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(570,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(581,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(590,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(605,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
>   1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(619,5):
>   error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'. 1>C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(3841,14): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4061,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4096,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'. 1>C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4103,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'. 1>C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4389,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4390,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4619,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'flags'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4647,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4657,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4674,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4686,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4696,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4712,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(5099,5): error
>   TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Try adding `"moduleResolution" : "node"` in your tsconfig.

Comment: @EricMartinez Please see the original question.

Comment: @EricMartinez I'm using *system module* and targeting the *es6*. Using *moduleResolution : node* may hide the error but I don't know whether this is a solution.

Comment: I compiled the same example but used Code and npm. It worked fine, can you post your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: check your order of importing js files in the `index.html` me to faced the same problem but i have done with my problem after reading this repo https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play/blob/master/index.html . hope it will help you to find the error

Comment: @vulkanino Do you have *web essentials* installed? I don't have web essentials installed which I don't want to.

Comment: @PardeepJain I haven't integrated *System.import* in index.html. At this stage the problem is a build error from a ts file. I don't think this is related to using *System.import* in index.html file.

Comment: First: if you have't integrate system.import then how will you set entry point for bootstrap file(Main component), Second: check for Core,common etc.. module from your node_modules bundle in the angular2 folder.

Comment: There should be an entry point with bootstrap. But the direction I'm taking is to use *gulp-typescript* to bundle the app. To make that happen, I have to compile the TS files. When everything is compiled, I can add the bootstrap. I have installed angular2 beta and it exists under node_modules folder.

Comment: @wonderfulworld no, I don't have web essentials installed. In the target I have ES5 and not ES6. Don't if that could help.

Comment: @wonderfulworld, just FYI the comment in the angular 2 module definitions file on DefinitelyTyped explicitly says you need "node" module resolution (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular2/angular2.d.ts)

Comment: Try closing VS and reopening your solution. This happened to me today. I had both of the aforementioned errors. After closing and reopening I was left with a couple small errors(real errors). After resolving those I had no more errors; all references were working accordingly.

Comment: why do we need tsconfig json? 
visual studio is supposed to be compiling ts automatically.
no criticism here, i also face this issue. im just confused on why we need tsconfig.json.

Comment: One last shot at this, try moving your project deeper into folder structure. For instance the default location of ```%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\``` . It looks to me like VS is searching same level directories and finding references in Program Files. If you can't perform the above then try excluding Program Files in your tsconfig.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488669/cannot-find-module-angular2-core) for a different stackoverflow question fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **typescript** has come long way, and the **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** is available at this point in time with typescript version 2.0.

I found it the hard way that any syntax error in **tsconfig.json** can cause the same problem. I had a comma at the end of the last key of the **compilerOptions**, and that caused the ts files unable to find the modules correctly.

Comment: Agreed. I had to Update Visual Studio to Update 3 and then install Typescript 2.2 from Tool > Extensions and Updates > Online.

Answer (score 1):

find the browser.d.ts file under your typings folder and drag into your app.ts or any ts file in your project.
you will get the ///reference xxxx, some error should be resolved

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I don't know what exactly did the trick.

- Installed Angualr using npm: 
  npm install Angular2
- Updated Visual Studio extension: 
  DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1