# Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator' with Typescript 1.7.5

Tags: typescript, angular

I installed NPM version of Typescript 1.7.5 and angular2 beta. While building the project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, I get this errors:

```
1>VSTSC : error TS2318: Build: Cannot find global type 'Iterable'.
1>VSTSC : error TS2318: Build: Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator'.
1>VSTSC : error TS2318: Build: Cannot find global type 'Symbol'.
1>VSTSC : error TS2468: Build: Cannot find global value 'Symbol'.
```

My tsconfig.json file is this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noLib": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "files": [
    "node_modules/angular2/typings/tsd.d.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2/typings/zone/zone.d.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

How to fix this error?

UPDATE:

I tried Martin Vseticka's answer. I get the following errors:

```
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\src\facade\lang.d.ts(2,22): error TS2304: Build: Cannot find name 'BrowserNodeGlobal'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(9,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(10,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(248,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(283,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(290,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(346,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(498,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(561,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(570,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(581,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(590,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(605,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(619,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(3841,14): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4061,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4096,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4103,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4389,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4390,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4619,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4647,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4657,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4674,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4686,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4696,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(4712,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\lib.es6.d.ts(5099,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
```

When I tried David Sherrit's answer, I get 14175 errors. The errors start with:

```
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\src\facade\lang.d.ts(2,22): error TS2304: Build: Cannot find name 'BrowserNodeGlobal'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(9,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(10,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(248,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(283,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
1>C:\Test\node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts(290,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
```

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noLib": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "files": [
    "node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

But still getting around 14162 errors which is primarily about duplicates. Turning the **noLib** to *true* did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to add `lib.d.ts` twice because you use `noLib` and you specifically add `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts` in `files`.

I would just remove `"node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts"` path.

There is also an issue with similar errors as you get: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5504

Comment: Please see my comments in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when `noLib` is set to `true` and `target` is set to `es6` it will include `lib.es6.d.ts` in addition to `lib.d.ts`. `lib.es6.d.ts` holds the definitions specific to ES6.

However, you are including `lib.d.ts`, which has this statement at the top of that file:

```
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
```

This overrides your `tsconfig.json` option and sets `noLib` to `true`; therefore, it doesn't include `lib.es6.d.ts`. This explains your errors.

If you want to continue using the definition files from `node_modules/typescript/...`, then you need to include `lib.es6.d.ts` as well:

```
"files": [
    "node_modules/angular2/typings/tsd.d.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2/typings/zone/zone.d.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts",
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
]
```

Otherwise, follow Martin's answer by keeping `noLib` as `false` and remove the reference to `lib.d.ts` in the list of files.

Comment: Please see my comments in the original question.

Comment: @wonderfulworld try removing `zone/zone.d.ts` and `tsd.d.ts` from the `files` array.

Comment: I added some comments in the original question.

Comment: @wonderfulworld maybe just completely removed `files` like the angular documentation shows: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html. I haven't used angular at all so I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: That was the route that I took first. But hit with this issue which I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312869/cannot-find-module-angular2-core-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1) So, I thought to set up the tsconfig so I can use Angular2 core.