# Typescript Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have problem with my code in typescript
After compile by tsc, I have errors like about cannot find some names.

```
app.ts(1,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'.
app.ts(8,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IteratorResult'.
app.ts(26,6): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
app.ts(26,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'.
```

My code is:

```
class Fib implements IterableIterator<number> {
    protected fn1 = 0;
    protected fn2 = 1;

    constructor(protected maxValue?: number) {}

    public next(): IteratorResult<number> {
        var current = this.fn1;
        this.fn1 = this.fn2;
        this.fn2 = current + this.fn1;

        if (this.maxValue && current <= this.maxValue) {
            return {
                done: false,
                value: current
            }
        }

        return {
            done: true
        }
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<number> {
        eturn this;
    }
}

fib = new Fib();
console.log(fib.next());
```

version tsc is Version 2.1.0-dev.20160716

Comment: What's your target in the compilation options? It should be `ES6`

Comment: My target is ES6:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}

Comment: I'm able to compile your code with target `ES6` (using tsc version `1.8.10`). You might have other things that affect the compilation ([check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321031/cannot-find-global-type-iterableiterator-with-typescript-1-7-5)).

Comment: Problem was that tsc cannot see my tsconfig.json, after run tsc -t ES6 app.ts code was compiled properly.

Comment: Consider writing your last comment as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer); after some time you will also be able to accept it, so that future users with a similar problem would benefit from it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem was that tsc cannot see my tsconfig.json, after run tsc -t ES6 app.ts code was compiled properly.

Comment: This only works as long as you want to compile a ES6 TypeScript file to a ES6 JavaScript file, what does not make any sense for me. So you could just change the file suffix `.ts` to `.js`. I am sceptical, if that is the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

I solve the same problem with `tsc -v 3.5.3` and `@types/node` *(tested es5 and es6)*

`npm install @types/node --save--dev`

and add `"node"` in the `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": [
    "./",
    "node"
  ]
}
```

Take a look here [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) for complete node types.