# Cannot find name 'Symbol' in whatwg-fetch type declaration file

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

The `d.ts` file at dt~whatwg-fetch includes the following declaration.

```
declare class Headers {
    // other code ommited
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, string]>;
}
```

We've tried to create a workaround interface without success. None of the following work. What will?

```
interface Symbol {}

interface Symbol<T> {}

interface Symbol {
   iterator: IterableIterator<[string, string]> 
}

interface Symbol<T> {
   iterator: IterableIterator<[string, string]> 
}
```

**Edit**

We've seen [Typescript Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420846/typescript-cannot-find-name-iterableiterator) and the recommendation is to target es6. Is that required?

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Symbol` is new to `ES6` and because of that you'll need to target your compiler to that.
To do that specify that the target in [the compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) is `"es6"`.

The definition for `Symbol` can be found in [the lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L5322) (while it's missing in the [default lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts))

---

#### Edit

You can just polyfill that part yourself, you just need to copy the needed parts from the `lib.es6.d.ts` file and put it in your own file and reference it.

I copied what needed for the code you posted and it's in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Symbol%20%7B%0A%09toString()%3A%20string%3B%0A%09valueOf()%3A%20Object%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20SymbolConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prototype%3A%20Symbol%3B%0A%09(description%3F%3A%20string%7Cnumber)%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09for(key%3A%20string)%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09keyFor(sym%3A%20symbol)%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20var%20Symbol%3A%20SymbolConstructor%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20SymbolConstructor%20%7B%0A%09hasInstance%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09isConcatSpreadable%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09match%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09replace%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09search%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09species%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09split%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09toPrimitive%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09toStringTag%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%09unscopables%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Symbol%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5BSymbol.toStringTag%5D%3A%20%22Symbol%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20SymbolConstructor%20%7B%0A%09iterator%3A%20symbol%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IteratorResult%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20done%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Iterator%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20next(value%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20IteratorResult%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%3F(value%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20IteratorResult%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20throw%3F(e%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20IteratorResult%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Iterable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()%3A%20Iterator%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IterableIterator%3CT%3E%20extends%20Iterator%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()%3A%20IterableIterator%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20Headers%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20code%20ommited%0A%20%20%20%20%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()%3A%20IterableIterator%3C%5Bstring%2C%20string%5D%3E%3B%0A%7D).
It might have more than actually needed, so play around with that.

Comment: The compilation does work when targeting es6. Is there a workaround for targeting es5 that does not involve setting up babel? Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4031

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 9):

Something that helped me to figure it out was adding the following setting to tsconfig.json:

```
"lib": [
    "es6",
    "dom"
]
```

After that i got another error of duplicate Promise declaration but i just removed the polyfill typing definition and worked fine.
It looks like the whatwg-fetch doesn't really needs the ES6 Symbol, the code can use the ES5 fallback:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11290