# Using generators in Typescript tsconfig

Tags: typescript, generator

#### What I'm Trying to Do

This is pretty simple, I want to use a generator function in Typescript and have it not error on me.

```
traverseTree = function* (tree: Section[]) {
    for (let branch of tree) {
        yield branch;
        if (branch.Children.length > 0)
            yield* traverseTree(branch.Children);
    }
}
```

#### What I'm Seeing

When compiling, I get the error `TS2318 Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator'`

#### What I've done so far

I've read a number of questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321031/cannot-find-global-type-iterableiterator-with-typescript-1-7-5) or [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16477), but none of the suggestions I've been able to find have made any difference.  I'm using Typescript 3.2.2 and trying to use a pretty simple generator function.  I've tried many things, but this is my current tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "none",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I've also tried adding `"downlevelIteration": true`, both true and false for `"noLib"`, in `"lib"`: not having `"esnext"`, using `"es6"`, and not having `"lib"` at all, I also messed with setting files:

```
"files": [
  "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts",
  "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
]
```

Nothing I do seems to make any difference, I always get the exact same error when compiling.

Comment: How do you compile your project?

Comment: The `compileOnSave` flag there, I just ctrl+s my project and VS compiles everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I was using Visual Studio 2019 Preview and for some reason 2017 worked fine.  Turns out I just needed to install the [3.2.2 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258) and everything worked perfectly in both versions.  I don't know why 2017 didn't care that the SDK wasn't installed and 2019 did, seems odd.