# cannot find module 'angular2/core'

Tags: visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015

[image]

These red squiggly lines say `cannot find module 'angular2/core'`,`cannot find module 'angular2/router'`,`cannot find module 'angular2/http'`.
I checked other posts in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312869/cannot-find-module-angular2-core-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1) but it seems they have no appropriate answer.

I also added a reference to the `d.ts` files as seen below but still not working.
[image]

Other posts say that I need to configure something in the `tsconfig.json` file but I am using Visual Studio and I see no need to use the tscompiler suggested by the angular team because Visual Studio should be able to compile ts files automatically.

Am I missing something?

**Is the `tsconfig.json` still required even if you use Visual Studio?**

**How do I get rid of these squiggly lines?**

Thanks!

(I am using Visual Studio 2015 and latest Typescript engine)

UPDATE:
I am not sure what exactly is the npm package manager. But I have a pre-built `package.json` file that was created when the project was created. I use this file for installing npm packages.
[image]

Comment: If you use npm as the package manager, right click the project > properties.  In Typescript build select CommonJs as the module loader

Comment: I right click on the project and clicked Properties.
I only see three tabs: Application, Build and Debug.
In the Build tab, there are `Produce outputs on build` and `Compile typescript on build` checkboxes. There's also the Configuration and Platform combo-boxes.
There is no module loader option.
This is an ASP.NET 5 web project.

Comment: Setting for CommonJS solved my problem in Visual Studio 2015 Pro.  thanks @pixelbits

Comment: It is all grayed out in Typescript build for me

Comment: @TomStickel it will be grayed out if you have tsconfig.json defined in your project. You can accomplish the same thing by adding this to the file: `"compilerOptions": { "module": "commonjs" }`

Comment: These typescript errors are such a beating.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For ASP.NET 5.0 applications in VS 2015, configuring typescript is a bit challenging.

Until the tooling around typescript improves, you can configure typescript manually:

```
Step 1: Right-click project, and Unload Project 
Step 2: Right-click the unloaded project, and Edit the .xproj file
Step 3: Add a PropertyGroup node, under the Project node:

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  </PropertyGroup>

Step 4: Right-click the unloaded project and Reload Project
Step 5: Re-build project
```

If you are still encountering the error where it cannot find the module, exit visual studio and reload the solution.

Comment: wow it worked! here's also the other XML tags for compiler options of typescript. `https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Setting-Compiler-Options-in-MSBuild-projects`. Just a tiny problem, the `ng` and `router` variables are still highlighted in red. I thought its just the ExperimentalDecorator, but it is already set to true.

Comment: I've tried the same thing with visual studio 2013, but still I am getting the same issue. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: maybe, i'll post my settings

Comment: I found this site extremely useful, it lists all of the options you can put in the project file.  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Setting-Compiler-Options-in-MSBuild-projects

Comment: Thanks @pixelbits It solved my build issues also. Excellent this is what I was looking for.

Comment: fabulous answer !!

Comment: I was do same as above but still getting same error

Comment: your answer is superb

Answer (score 9):

Here is my working settings:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
  <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
  <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>System</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptOutFile />
  <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
  <TypeScriptOutDir />
  <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
  <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptMapRoot />
  <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
  <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Restart Visual Studio after applying this to your web project.

Comment: This is the best solution if you are using node.js/npm and following the angular2 tutorial from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: This set of tags worked for me. I think `<TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>` was the key to fixing the bug I was seeing (same as what the OP posted).

Comment: Note that Condition is set to Release here and Debug in the previous example

Comment: Restart is not necessary just unload and reload your project.

Answer (score 7):

For VS2015, go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> TypeScript -> Project -> General then tick "Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project" then select "Use CommonJS code generation for modules.."

Comment: I did that , but that still didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 6):

This is how I fixed the problem in VS2015 :

> - Open to the project property window
> - Navigate to the **TypeScript Build** tab
> - Select CommonJS as module system as shown in image below

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't have VSCode. There should be a way to modify project properties.

Comment: I dont have that window in VS2015

Comment: In VS 2015, right click on the ASP.NET 4.x project and select Properties. This dialog should then appear. The "TypeScript Build" tab is at the bottom on the left as shown in the screen shot above.

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered this error and what worked for me was, unloading the project and checking the .csproj file. I found that this snippet was added there -

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ClientApp\components\componentname\componentname.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Removing this code, saving the csproj then reloading the project worked.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to install it is with npm package manager, because angular2 is shipped with typing now. Your editor will recognize all import locations...

Comment: i added angular2 through my project's package.json.

Answer (score 0):

```
This has to be done for both 'Debug' and 'Release' then only it works in VS 2013. Like below..

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>system</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    </TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>system</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and give some context. What exactly are saying?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on installing ionic 2 - i installed all the packages (package.json update) and updated my npm to v3. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Developing with the [ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Starter Application](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) template from Mads Kristensen.  I had a similar problem starting a new directory with Typescript files.

My solution was more simple than modifying the project file.  I just copied the tsconfig.json from the ClientApp folder where all of the typescript files were to my new folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on "**package.json**"

and select "**Restore Packages**" 
after installation of Packages build it... your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

This is an Interesting issue, apart from the reasons and solution mentioned above, one can get this error on following scenarios.

1. NPM (Node Package Manager) is not installed on the machine

   Fix: Install NPM from https://nodejs.org/en/

   [image: Probably NPM not installed or not configured]
2. If you are still getting this error after Installing NPM, there could be NPM configuration issue.  Refer to this [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2015FixingDependenciesNpmNotInstalledFromFseventsWithNodeOnWindows.aspx) to setup NPM configuration properly

Answer (score 0):

1. In Visual Studio 2015, go to "Tools" menu and click on "Options...". You will 
   be able to see a tree structure on the left side of the opened window.
2. Expand "Projects and Solutions" and then select "External Web Tools". Now move 
   "$(PATH)" entry above the "$(DevEnvDir)" entry.
3. Click OK. Restart the Visual Studio.
4. Now right click on the "package.json" file in the solution explorer and click 
   on "Restore Packages".

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same problem when I am using eclplse editor . I have executed the below command in my cmd window and I have restarted my eclipse . It is working as expected.

*npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12 @angular/forms*

Answer (score 0):

- Try to run **npm install** command (will install missing lib in your project)
- ReOpen your folder/project

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "**package.json**"
then select Install packages option it will open terminal and automatically navigate to the correct root folder and will install the required dependencies.

The package.json lists down all the list of dependencies the project needs to run.